# Slow/inefficent Javascript code development cycle in Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, debugging

I'm using Symfony 2.8 with jQuery and I created `my.js` and wanted to debug into `my.js`.

Now I found that it's very slow or inefficient to debug the javascript code in my case.

My `my.js` code is in `Resources\public\js` folder and it's linked in a .twig file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/project/js/my.js') }}"></script>
```

Every time I updated `my.js` code, I need to run

> php app/console assets:install web

and then

> php app\console server:run

I would say this is very inefficient to debug a javascript code. What I want is a press of F5 key to reload `my.js` and begin my debug in chrome.

Can I do that?

Comment: if you don't have Assetic (Assets manager) or do not use gulp/webpack. The quickies way wold be **moving** from `src/<BUNDLE_NAME>/Resources/public/js/my.js` to a web/js/my.js and in twig  `src="{{ asset('js/my.js') }}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `assets:install` command you can use the symlink-option:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web/
```

This will create a symlink instead of copying the files. That means all your changes should be automatically reflected when reloading in your browser. Older versions of Windows don't support this, i.e. will still do a hard copy instead, but from Windows 7 on this is probably the easiest way to solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

As long as I know - working in DEV mode is what you're looking for.
Look at documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html) -> in particular at `use_controller`. So in your app/config.yml you should have

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
```

and in your app/config_dev.yml

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

then just run php app\console server:run and add `app_dev.php` to the url

something like `http://localhost/app_dev.php`

Comment: Assetic has nothing to do with the `assets:install` command. Assetic is a different library that supports preprocessing of your asset files implemented in PHP. `assets:install` on the other hand does not much more than copying/symlinking asset files from bundles to the publicly accessible directory (that's usually `public` nowadays in Flex based applications).

Comment: yes, but since OP uses Symfony 2.8 Assetic should be "on board". OPs desire was just pressing F5 (reload) in order to refresh and work (debug) with a newer version. You said `assets:install` just copy files to a public dir. So it **will not help**  .

Comment: It copies **or** symlinks depending on how you call `assets:install` and which OS you are using (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942127/2289865)).